# Issues while trying to collect nested lists in Drools

Tags: drools

I am facing some difficulties while trying to write a rule with Drools (6.4.Final). 
Either my rule is not completely correct, or I am ending up writing several rules for the same goal but without conviction. I'd like to get your opinions based on your experiences and/or references to help me.

I have a fact (type C) that contains a list of E.

Each E :

- has an int attribute which is a year
- may have a list of R

Each R :

- has a type
- has an amount

I want to check, for one/each year, if the sum of the amounts of R of a certain type exceeds a value.
If it exceeds, I want to insert a fact (X) with all the E that are behind.

**My first try was** :

```
rule "Sum of R exceed for one year"
when
   C( $listOfE : listOfE )

// Pick one E
   E( $year : year ) from $listOfE

// All Es of the same year
// "collectLists" is a custom accumulate function that simply adds all the elements of a list
  accumulate ( E(year == $year, $listofR : listofR ) from $listOfE;
            $allR : collectLists($listofR))

  // Check the sum
  // "sumbd" is  a custom accumulate function that simply adds BigDecimal (sum is broken for that in 6.4)
  accumulate ( R( type == « X », $amount : amount ) from $allR;
               $sum : sumbd($amount);
               $cumulAnnee > 20000)

then
  insert( new X($year, $elements));
end
```

It is working but there is an issue with elements in X that may not have any R or have R that do not match the expecting type...

**My second try is**:

Several but simpler rules declaring a type to help accumulate data and working with single E.

```
declare YearAccumulation
  year : int
  allE : java.util.List
  sum : BigDecimal
end

rule "Sum of R exceed for one year (1)"
when
   C( $listOfE : listOfE ) 
   $e : E( $year : year ) from $listOfE 

   // No accumulation for this year yet
   not(YearAccumulation( year == $year ))

   accumulate ( R( type == « X », $amount : amount ) from $e.listOfR;
               $amounts : collectList($amount),
               $sum : sumbd($amount);
               $amounts.size > 0)

then
   YearAccumulation ya = new YearAccumulation();
   ya.setYear($year);
   List allE = new ArrayList();
   allE.add($element);
   ya.setAllE(allE);
   ya.setSum($sum);
   insert(ya);
end

rule "Sum of R exceed for one year (2)"
when
   C( $listOfE : listOfE )       
   $e : E( $year : year ) from $listOfE

   accumulate ( R( type == « X », $amount : amount ) from $e.listOfR;
               $amounts : collectList($amount),
               $sum : sumbd($amount);
               $amounts.size > 0)
   // Do not process already processed E
   $ya : YearAccumulation ( year == $year, $e not memberOf allE)
then
   $ya.getAllE().add($e);
   $ya.setSum($ya.getSum().add($sum)); 
   update($ya);
end

rule "Sum of R exceed for one year (3)"
when
   YearAccumulation ($year:year, $elements:allE, sum > 20000)
then
   insert( new X($year, $elements));
end
```

But I don't feel confident with this solution and it looks (quite) complicated to get the result.
Eventually I'd like to have a simple rule(s) that will be easy to understand and maintain.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach would be to collect all sums per year in one pass over all E and R and return a `Map<YearType,BigDecimal>` where `YearType` combines a year and a type, and you can extract the Entry objects to inspect the BigDecimal etc. etc.

I'm not sure whether you can write a custom accumulate function returning a Map, but it can be done using the "traditional" accumulate syntax where you have init, action and result clauses to program anything you need.

This is a short version of the accumulate you might use:

```
Map() from accumulate( E( $lr: listOfR != null, $y: year )
                       init( Map m = new HashMap(); )
                       action( for( int i = 0; i < $lr.size(); ++i ){
                                 //... add to m.get($y) observing R's type
                               } )
                       result( m ) )
```

Comment: Thank you. It would be a way to go indeed. But it seems to be more like my first attempt.

Comment: I mean, you don't check R type and you loose the information about which Es has the Rs that are taken into account.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem composing the Map key from a year and a type. I'll add that to my answer.

Comment: Such algorithms may be better off in Java, implemented in class C, e.g. `Map<YearType,BigDecimal> auditOfR` as it doesn't appear that computing the sums is subject to volatile business rules and should be held among the rules. Evaluation - years and types with excessive sums - is still possible within the rules.

Comment: Even if you seems to forget the need to also keep track of all the Es that eventually have these Rs having the right type and having a cumulated amount exceeding the value (20000). I understand your point.

Comment: After some thinking, the same kind of accumulation may be needed by other rules, so it would indeed be better to do the computation off in java before fireing all rules or doing it lazilly at the first call by a rule.
Thanks again.